# How to rebuild my PATH in script?

Tags: scripts

I have extracted my PATH to a file and listed it as such:

```
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
.
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/client/bin
/usr/java/default/bin
/usr/kerberos/bin
/usr/local/bin
/bin
/usr/bin
```

I now wish to extract it from this file and restore it as one line in a new file with colons between each directory. I am getting an empty file can some show me what I am doing wrong please? This is the command I am executing to perform the restore to file:

```
echo -e ${bash_list tr \\ :\n} > bash_PATH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` takes input from STDIN (standard input). Try this:

```
$ tr '\n' ':' > output_file  < input_file
```

You have used a syntax for Bash's parameter expansion but you are using a file as a parameter which is not correct as the parameter can only be variable or a special shell parameter.

To do what you are trying using only `bash`:

```bsh
$ var="$(<bash_list)"
$ echo "${var//$'\n'/:}" > bash_PATH
```

Now `bash_PATH` file will contain:

```bsh
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:.:/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/client/bin:/usr/java/default/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Also note that you have duplicate directory names in "$PATH" (hope those are intentional for the sake of example), to remove the duplicates without changing the ordering you can try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11939/68757).

Comment: you should run that trough uniq first as there are dups in the path. Not strictly necessary ....

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: noted that but chosen to ignore as `sort -u` or `sort | uniq` will break the ordering..

Comment: @heemayl there are other ways to uniq: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/how-to-get-only-the-unique-results-without-having-to-sort-data

Comment: You all are awesome! Thank you for your time and instruction!!

Comment: You could perhaps avoid the `cat` using a construct like `var="$(<bash_list)"`? or maybe use an array: something like `(mapfile -t arr < bash_list ; IFS=: ; echo "${arr[*]}")`

Comment: @steeldriver: Thanks for these..i have added the first one..